# Entrada de Cron para chamar scheduler do laravel sem funcionar

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5

Estou começando agora com o laravel, coloquei um projeto teste dele junto com mongodb em um servidor amazon, mas depois que eu insiro a seguinte entrada única "* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1" no CRONTAB como o trecho na documentação do laravel sobre 'scheduling' ensina:

**Starting The Scheduler
Here is the only Cron entry you need to add to your server:
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. Then, Laravel evaluates your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.**

Segue abaixo o codigo que estou querendo executar...:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o (Kernel.php) do laravel que editei para chamar a cada minuto o que está no método ;"handle" no print anterior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, afinal das contas...minha dúvida é:
eu coloquei a entrada cron no programa crontab do linux para poder chamar o meu laravel, é assim que a documentação pede... mas depois de instalar o cron com o comando que citei no começo do texto, o método que falei antes(handle) não executa, não acontece nada...
Alguêm poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sem ver o seu código, fica difícil entender o que você está tentando fazer. Veja mais em [mcve].

Comment: Vou por...Obrigado victor!

Comment: Leia aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595